# css display:table-cell; is not displaying at 100% of the width of the outer <dl>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<dl>` and `<dd>` that I am trying to convert into a table cells but I am not able to get the  widths to display corectly.

The outer `<dl>` is 100%  and the `<dt>`'s are 20% and 80%. Why dont the `<dt>` together per row display at a 100% of the width of the outer `<dl>`

All I should see is red and blue and no yellow

Here is my fiddle  - thanks for the help

http://jsfiddle.net/35Gmm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the display to `table` on the definition list

```
dl{
   display:table;
}
```

and probably want to convert one `dd` into an `dt`

```
    <dl>
      <dt>hot drink</dt>
      <dd>cold drink</dd>
    </dl>

    dl > dt {
        background:red;
        width: 20%;
    }

    dl > dd {
        background:blue;
        width: 80%;
    }
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/35Gmm/30/)

But why would you want to use a definition list (a list of terms (`dt`), which you are then offering an explanation for (`dd`) ), if your data is semantically not appropriate for it? (Or was the fiddle just some random sample data?)

Comment: thanks for the help - it was just  random example Im just trying to grasp the concept. and Id rather keep the dd:nth-child concept as I need to add more cells. thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this css this will work fine **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/EZtDj/)**

```
dl{
   display:table;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

change dl > dd:nth-child(2) to dl > dd:nth-child(1)

It will work.

Comment: is it a zero based index?

Comment: dd
        {
            display:inline-block;
            
        }

        dl > dd:nth-child(1)
        {
            background:red;
            width: 19%;
        }

        dl > dd:nth-child(2)
                {
            background:blue;
            width: 80%;
        }

Comment: `nth-child` is not zero based?